# Error:(22, 30) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Sensor

Tags: android

Am Trying to display sensors available in a device...here is my code i have hard time knowing wht to do...

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SensorManager sMgr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView sensorsData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        sMgr = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List list = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        for (Sensor sensor : list) {
            data.append(sensor.getName() + "\n");
            data.append(sensor.getVendor() + "\n");
            data.append(sensor.getVersion() + "\n");
        }
        sensorsData.setText(data);
    }
}
```

and the error is on this line

```
for (Sensor sensor : list) {
```

Comment: `List<Sensor> list =`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
List<Sensor> list = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

instead of

```
List list = sMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```